# Issue Importing the Paradise Papers Dataset into Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

Hej all,

I am having an issue with importing the [Paradise Papers dataset](https://www.icij.org/investigations/paradise-papers/data-ever-added-offshore-leaks-database/) into a Neo4j (3.3.2) database.

It seems that the data is imported correctly into the database, as reported by `neo4j-admin import`.

```
...
IMPORT DONE in 1m 4s 889ms.
Imported:
  867931 nodes
  1657838 relationships
  17838925 properties
Peak memory usage: 488.28 MB
...
```

However, after importing the data, the database seems to be empty, as reported by the Cypher queries `MATCH (n) RETURN count(n);` and `CALL apoc.meta.graph();`

```
...
count(n)
0
nodes, relationships
[], []
...
```

The following link points to a script, which should reproduce my issue. It is a Bash script for OS X/BSD (I think the `-E` switch for `sed` does not exist on Linux). Additionally, the script requires Docker to be installed and running on the system.

https://github.com/HelgeCPH/cypher_kernel/blob/master/example/import_data.sh

To run the script quickly:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HelgeCPH/cypher_kernel/master/example/import_data.sh
chmod u+x import_data.sh
./import_data.sh
```

I cannot see what I am doing wrong. Do I have to point to the database explicitely when running `cypher-shell`?

Checking on the container, the database files exist (`ls -ltrh data/databases/graph.db`) and their timestamps correspond to the time when importing the data.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: `neo4j-admin import` command should be used when the database is stopped. Or I don't see any stop/start of the server in your script. What folder do you have inside `data/databases` neo4j folder ?

Comment: Right, I forgot to toggle the DB engine. I added two corresponding lines to the linked script. But unfortunately, this does not change anything in the result.
In the `data/databases` directory, I create one with the name `graph.db`. After the input it contains all these `neostore*` files and an `index` file, see https://github.com/HelgeCPH/cypher_kernel/blob/master/example/ls_result.txt

Comment: I just ran a small test in doing the exact same operation of importing the Paradise Papers dataset into a Neo4j instance that is running directly on the host, i.e., not in a Docker container. There everything seems to work as expected. That is, after **a)** `neo4j stop`, **b)** `neo4j-admin import ...`, **c)** `neo4j start`, `echo 'MATCH (n) RETURN count(n);' | cypher-shell -u ... -p ...` returns the count of `867931` nodes as reported by `neo4j-admin import`.

So, that mean that the issue is related to Neo4j running in a container?

Comment: you have a pull request ^^

Comment: Thank you very much! So in essence, the issue was that

Comment: Thank you very much! So in essence, the issue was that I used `docker exec neo4j sh -c 'neo4j stop'` instead of `docker restart neo4j` and that the queries after importing were executed before the DB was properly restarted. I can see that with your 5s break everything works nicely. On top of it, thank you for showing how to import nodes with their types set properly via the `--nodes:Type` flag. I did not know it and the empty schema of the second query would have been my next question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had multiple errors on your script :

- Nodes were not loaded, because in the CSV the `:ID` column is not set. That's why I have added this part :

  for file in import/csv_paradise_papers/*.nodes.*.csv 
  do
    sed -i -E '1s/node_id/node_id:ID/' $file
  done
- Labels of node were also not set. It's possible to set them directly in the command line like this : `--nodes:MyLabel`
- If you do a query on Neo4j when the server is restarting, you will probably receive an error because the server is not yet ready. That's why I have added a `sleep 5` at the end. 
  A better approach would be to wait until you have response from the server with someting like this :

  until $(curl --output /dev/null --silent --head --fail http://localhost:7474); do
      printf '.'
      sleep 1
  done
- Last point, I don't know why, but if you do the restart of neo4j inside the container, you will not see the imported data. But if you restart the container itself it's OK ...